# Why doesn't the inside of jquery .get() function respond?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drupal, get

I am using jquery 1.3.2. I'm using the .get() method to read a .txt file from a server. Currently, the method is retrieving the correct file (I know this because it is logged by firebug); however, I would like to set the html of a span tag to read text from the file like this:

```
drupal_add_js('$(document).ready(function(){
     $.get("' . $path . 'templates/first_order_decay.txt"), function(data){
        $("#embeddableContainer").html(data);
     }
  });', 'inline');
```

I am also using drupal 6.x as a content management system. Nothing inside of the innermost function (`function(data){...}`) works. I've tried console.log as well as alert. Neither do anything. Because of this, I believe the reason my html is not being set is because that line of code is not being reached for some reason. Again I say that the method is retrieving the file from the server. What seems to be going wrong here? Why does nothing inside the innermost function work? Could it be because of jquery 1.3.2?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a syntax error. It should have been:

```
drupal_add_js('$(document).ready(function(){
     $.get("' . $path . 'templates/first_order_decay.txt", function(data){
        $("#embeddableContainer").html(data);
     });
  });', 'inline');
```